# codec type or id mismatches when using usb_cam

Tags: ros, usb-camera, camera, webcam, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to use the usb_cam package to integrate my logitech c920 into my project. Unfortunately, I get the following output when I use mjeg as pixel format:

```
[swscaler @ 0x4453c7a0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv422p to rgb24.
```

Due to the high resolution pictures is this compression necessary, otherwise my system would be to slow. I have a lack of 3-4 seconds with yuyv as pixel format.

I followed [this guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) to reinstall ffmpeg from source but it didn't change anything...
I would very much appreciate any ideas to solve this issue. Thanks

### **EDIT1:**

I found this [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/10262/no-accelerated-colorspace-conversion-found/) where they mention that the 6.2 Version should work. I installed it but the error message is now:

```
[mjpeg @ 0x4461b040]codec type or id mismatches
I could find a decoderCould not open MJPEG Decoder
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48686/codec-type-or-id-mismatches-when-using-usb_cam/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-12-12**:
I'm afraid I have had this problem in the past and it has nothing to do with ROS. Rather, it is a ffmpeg issue, as you found out. So either you figure out how to get ffmpeg work with it or you'll have to change webcam.

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-12-12**:
that what I don't know... I looked up the code under sensor_message/image_encoding.cpp which just offers me rgb16 and not rgb24 how can I change that?

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-12-13**:
@georgebrindeiro Do you know a HD Webcam which supports some compression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know any HD Webcams which support some compression and work well with ffmpeg, but maybe you will find the information you need in the [OpenCV Camera Compatibility lists](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS).

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0